# IntToVisibilityConverter In WPF

Tags: c#, xaml, ivalueconverter

I have a `StackPanel` and `Border` and what I need to achieve is whenever the `Children.Count` property of the panel is 0 the Border become visible. I tried to many times but don't know what's wrong with my code!?

```
public class IntToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (value is int integer && integer == 0) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Xaml

```
<local:IntToVisibilityConverter x:Key="IntConverter"/>

<Border Visibility="{Binding ElementName=MainPagesStackPanel, Path=Children.Count, Converter={StaticResource IntConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: I assume the `StackPanel.Children.Count` doesn't raise a change notification (it is not a dependency property and not supporting INPC). So while your converter code seems technically ok, it is probably simply not invoked when children are added / removed from that panel

Comment: if the elements in that panel refer to a collection in your viemodel (for example some ObservableCollection) you might bind to the Count property of that collection. As far as I remember - PropertyChanged is raised for changes in ObservableCollection.Count...